# How could a https site enable external http link without warning from browser?

Tags: ssl, https, web

I have mixed content in my https website, but once I have http conent like external link to outside, the browser will warning "this is not a trusted site"

As the links of http cannot be removed, how can I walk around this issue?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can have links to `http` content. The most common thing when this happens is that you have `src` attributes with `http` in them. If you're for instance getting jquery code from an API, try switching to `https`.